# Attempting to populate a <select> with an array

Tags: javascript

```
<form name="vegForm" action="veg.aspx" >
    <select onchange='this.form.submit()'>
          <script type="text/javascript">
             for (i = 0; i < veg.length; i++) {
                 document.write('<option>')
                veg[i]                   
                 document.write('</option>')                    
            }
         </script>            
     </select>

 </form>
```

As you can imagine im quite new and having problem witht the above :/
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: And what exactly *is* the problem?

Comment: As you're a beginner, you might want to get on the right track right from the start, so maybe have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `veg[i]` with `document.write(veg[i])` and your code works

Example

```
    <form name="vegForm" action="veg.aspx" >
        <select onchange='this.form.submit()'>
              <script type="text/javascript">

              veg = [1,2,3,4,5] ;

                 for (i = 0; i < veg.length; i++) {
                     document.write('<option>')
                     document.write(veg[i])                   
                     document.write('</option>')                    
                }
             </script>            
         </select>

     </form>
```

Thanks
:)

Comment: Thanks!, this sorted it for me!

Comment: You are welcome... you need to accept the question for people to know its resolved

Comment: Might work in this case, but consider: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: @ Tim Medora nice one ... Bu i think is is still a beginner and still very fresh ... That might be a little above his level

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `document.write()` to append html code. Either use `document.createElement` and `node.appendChild` afterwards or (simpler) `innerHTML` as follows:

```
<form name="vegForm" action="veg.aspx" >
    <select onchange='this.form.submit()' id="mySelect">           
     </select>
</form>

<script>
  (function(){
    var out = '';
    for (i = 0; i < veg.length; i++) {
      out += '<option>' + veg[i] + '</option>';
    }
    document.querySelector( '#mySelect' ).innerHTML = out;
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/ur9fr/

**JavaScript**

```
var veg = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
var ddl = document.getElementById("ddlVeg");
 for (i = 0; i < veg.length; i++) {
     var o = document.createElement("option");
     o.text = o.value = veg[i];
     ddl.appendChild(o);                
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="vegForm" action="veg.aspx" >
    <select onchange='this.form.submit()' id="ddlVeg">
    </select>
</form>​
```

If you are new to JavaScript, you would find a helper library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to be extremely beneficial. It abstracts some of the underlying complexity and ensures reasonable compatibility across browsers.

jQuery version of the same problem: http://jsfiddle.net/a95Vt/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<form name="vegForm" action="veg.aspx" >
    <select onchange='this.form.submit()'>          
    </select>
</form>
<script>
    //array created here - but get it from where ever you need..
    var veg = ["leek", "turnip", "carrot"];
    (function(){
        var form = document.getElementsByName("vegForm")[0];
        var select = form.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];

        for(var i = 0, len = veg.length; i < len; i++){
           var val = veg[i]; 
           selection.options[i] = new Option(val, val);  
        }
     })();
</script>
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3SS8/3/.